# Automatically copy files to external USB drive when connected to laptop

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, bashrc, external-hdd

I want to copy some files/folders to a USB Flash Drive, SSD, or HDD after I connect them to my laptop. I don't want to detect the USB, do extra stuff, etc.. I just want to run a script from my terminal, which copies specified files to a specified external drive.

Earlier I have written

```
alias onetbeans='sudo /usr/local/netbeans-8.2/bin/netbeans'
```

in my .bashrc file to open netbeans by just writing onetbeans.

I wished to know if there is anything similar I can do for copying files?
I would only copy some specific files/folder which I can mention.

Example:

```
cp -R [folder to copy] /media/shray/[name of usb/hard drive]
```

Now, my [folder to copy] is constant. But how do I take care of different names a usb can take? For example, if I need to copy to a usb named "myusb" then I can write

```
alias customcopy='cp -R ~/Desktop/copyFolder /media/usb/myusb/'
```

But how do I take care of changing USB drive names?

Comment: Is it always the same USB-drive or will they vary?

Comment: they will vary @Fiximan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a bash function in your `.bashrc` for this.

```
customcopy() {
    cp -R ~/Desktop/copyFolder/ "$1"
}
```

After sourcing your `.bashrc`, you can use it like this:

```
customcopy /media/usb/myusb/
```